# Java / LibGDX show JOptionPane in front of fullscreen window

Tags: java, swing, libgdx, fullscreen, joptionpane

I'm making a game in java with libGDX, and I'm currently working on the options menu. I made an ImageButton using Scene2D.ui. When the button is clicked, I want a JOptionPane dialog to appear on screen. This works fine as long as the game is in windowed mode, but if it is in fullscreen mode the JOptionPane dialog appears behind the window. How do I get it to appear on top of all windows, even if one of them is in fullscreen mode?

I've tried using this code, but it doesn't seem to make any difference:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

The only solution I can think of would be to create a custom dialog that wouldn't have it's own window, but that would require a lot of work and feels unneccesary.

Thanks!

Comment: `JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(frame, "information",
"information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);` where `frame` is the window `JOptionPane` should be on top. Try that

Comment: Just wondering, Is there a specific reason why you want to use a JOptionPane  / JDialog instead of something that libgdx provides?

Comment: @second no there isn't, I just thought it was a simple solution.

Comment: I found that doing a dialog in libgdx is similiar the way you do it in html. If you want a dialog you just place the component directly over the other. If you mix different framworks you always have to deal with some unexpected side effects like the issue you are having.

Comment: Scene2d even provides a dialog class and that works really well. Additionally it works on all platforms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `JOptionPane` linking it with its parent frame/dialog. It is the first parameter of the static methods, as [described in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInternalMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)).

An example:

```
JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(frame, "information", "information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Where `frame` is the window `JOptionPane` should be on top.

Comment: So, I might be doing this the wrong way, but when I tried using dialog.getParent() as frame, I got a runtime exception ->     
JOptionPane: parentComponent does not have a valid parent

Comment: It is hard to tell why you are having this error without seeing a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)